# Detach jQuery not working when reattaching on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove and add parts of my nav bar with an icon depending on how the user adjusts the scale width.

The javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    var store;
    function detach() {
        if ($window.width() > 720) {
            store = $(".dropdown").detach();
        }
        else {
            $("nav").append(store);
            store = null;
        }
    }

    detach();
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        detach();
    });
});
```

The nav bar I am trying to remove:

```
<div class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="#">Login</a>
         <a href="#">Register</a>
       </div>
     </div>
```

This script succeeds in 'detaching' the icon from the nav bar, however when the user scales it back down, it will not reattach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is because you lose the reference to `store`. If you get the reference when the page loads the code will work:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $store = $(".dropdown");

function detach() {
  if ($window.width() > 720) {
    $store.detach();
  } else {
    $("nav").append($store);
  }
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  detach();
}).trigger('resize');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yueervsz/2) - remember to drag the result panel width to see it working

***However*** using JS as a crutch for responsive UI is a bad idea. Instead you can use a CSS @media query to do what you require in a much more simple way:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  nav .dropdown { display: block; }
}

.dropdown { display: none; }
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yueervsz/1/)